# Is there any way to detect a program's version in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-format

I tried to use clang-format to format my cpp project. My cmake file is as follows:

```
... 
find_program(CLANG_FORMAT_BIN_NAME NAMES clang-format-3.8 PATH /usr/bin/)
if(NOT CLANG_FORMAT_BIN_NAME-NOTFOUND)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_SOURCE_FILES *.cc *.h)
    add_custom_target(
            clang-format
            COMMAND ${CLANG_FORMAT_BIN_NAME}
            -style=google
            -i
            ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}
    )
endif()
...
```

When I use `make clang-format`, everything goes well. Now let's step further, I want to use clang-format without specifying its exact version. Is there any way to achieve this goal? I have tried to change my CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
find_program(CLANG_FORMAT_BIN_NAME NAMES clang-format-* PATH /usr/bin/)
if(NOT CLANG_FORMAT_BIN_NAME-NOTFOUND)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE ALL_SOURCE_FILES *.cc *.h)
    add_custom_target(
            clang-format
            COMMAND ${CLANG_FORMAT_BIN_NAME}
            -style=google
            -i
            ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}
    )
endif()
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You could use `GLOB` to do a wildcard search in `/usr/bin/` or `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` directory (which `find_program` uses), and then could pass the found versions into `find_program` if you want that `find_program` set the variables accordingly.

Comment: CMake-way could be enumerating all possible executable names in the `NAMES` clause: `NAMES clang-format-3-8 clang-format-3-7 clang-format-3-6 <...>`. (The list of names could be created from the list of known versions by using `list(TRANSFORM <versions-list> PREPEND> "clang-format-")`.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I finally use `file(GLOB CLANG_FORMAT_BIN_NAME /usr/bin/clang-format-[0-9]*)` to solve my problem.